# Multiple streamhandlers

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to beef up the logging in my Python scripts and I am grateful if could share best practices with me. For now I have created this little script (I should say that I run Python 3.4)

```
import logging
import io
import sys

def Streamhandler(stream, level, format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"):
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
    ch.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(format)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    return ch


# get the root logger
logger = logging.getLogger()

stream = io.StringIO()
logger.addHandler(Streamhandler(stream, logging.WARN))

stream_error = io.StringIO()
logger.addHandler(Streamhandler(stream_error, logging.ERROR))

logger.addHandler(Streamhandler(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG))

print(logger)
for h in logger.handlers:
    print(h)
    print(h.level)

# 'application' code   # goes to the root logger!
logging.debug('debug message')
logging.info('info message')
logging.warning('warn message')
logging.error('error message')
logging.critical('critical message')

print(stream.getvalue())
print(stream_error.getvalue())
```

I have three handlers, 2 of them write into a io.StringIO (this seems to work). I need this to simplify testing but also to send logs via a HTTP email service. And then there is a Streamhandler for the console. However, logging.debug and logging.info messages are ignored on the console here despite setting the level explicitly low enough?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you didn't set the level on the logger itself:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Also, you define a `logger` but do your calls on `logging` - which will call on the root logger. Not that it will make any difference in your case since you didn't specify a name for your logger, so `logging.getLogger()` returns the root logger.

wrt/ "best practices", it really depends on how "complex" your scripts are and of course on your logging needs.

For self-contained simple scripts with simple use cases (single known environment, no concurrent execution, simple logging to a file or stderr etc), a simple call to `logging.basicConfig()`  and direct calls to `logging.whatever()` are usually good enough.

For anything more complex, it's better to use a distinct config file - either in `ini` format or as Python dict (using `logging.dictConfig`), split your script into distinct module(s) or package(s) each defining it's own named logger (with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`) and only keep your script itself as the "runner" for your code, ie: configure logging, import modules, parse command line args and call the main function - preferably in a try/except block as to properly log any unhandled exception before crashing.

Comment: I guess I kind of end up with parsing around the logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger") to module(s) and package(s) further down the line. I am sceptical about having module(s) defining their own loggers...

Comment: @tschm a module needs a logger to log anything, and all it needs is a `import logging; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` line at the beginning (**no** config done here). This is the intended way to do logging: loggers form a hierarchy based on the logger name ('foo.bar' is a child of 'foo' which is a child of 'root') and if not explicitely configured the logger propagates to it's parent - so doing this way makes sure we have this hierarchy properly built and then you get full control over logging config per package / module / submodule if you want, or can just configure the root logger.

Comment: It's starting to make sense :-). My main function is calling like 3 different packages though (which may indicate that I should do some refactoring). At this stage I decided to go with def f(x, logger=None): and include logger = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__) in the functions and classes that use logging. So I can parse the logger of my main function to  my clients but I don't have to. Using this (dirty) trick I need to configure only one logger to rule them all.

Comment: That's **not** a "dirty trick", that's exactly why the `logging`package has been designed this way: to avoid having to pass loggers everywhere down the call chain and cleanly decouple call to the loggers (lib's duty) from logging configuration (application's duty).

Comment: There is still a small issue I haven't solved yet. If I have a logger with multiple handlers the logger will expose those handlers as a list. Is there a chance to assign a name to each handler and expose a dictionary here? E.g. code like this logger.handlers["MyErrorStreamHandler"].stream.getValue()???

Comment: handlers have a name so you can at least build a dict, ie `handlers_map = dict((h.name, h) for h in logger.handlers)`. Just remember that only loggers explicitely configured will have a handler - you may have to recursively check the logger's parent(s) for existing handlers. If you configure the loggers by code, you may prefer to keep a direct reference to your handlers.

Answer (score 1):

A `logger` has a [threshold level](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) too, you need to set it to `DEBUG` first:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```